# I am trying to come up with a regex to check a specific string layout

Tags: regex

I have the following string:`-stage=build` and there will be variations of this such as:

`-task=do`, `-command=ls\-ltra`, `-working-directory=\path\to\my\folder` etc.

So I am trying to come up with the regex that is going to be able to check the strings against a specific formation as illustrated in the examples above.

This is what I got so far: `^-\w+=[A-Za-z]+\\+[A-Za-z]`

which seems to be able to capture things like: `-stage=hello\rtgh`

But I have issues with continuing after the `\`. I am not able to detect the `tgh` bit. How can I improve my regex?

The pattern in general is:

`-(letters with no space)-(letters with no space)=(any letters, numbers, * etc and a literal escape to escape spaces)`

Comment: Maybe [`^-[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)?=[^\s\\]*(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/6xYdC3/1)?

Comment: Thanks. Works. I will look at how this is constructed. Final question, how do we usually forbid specific characters, like if we need to prevent a `.` like in for example make this illegal `-stage.a=banana`?

Comment: If the above regex works, your question is not clear: you should specify that a backslash in your strings forms escape sequences (a backslash will be written with double backslash, and `-working-directory=\path\to\my\folder` should actually be `-working-directory=\\path\\to\\my\\folder`). A dot is not matched in that position anyway, no need excluding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer.

Assuming a backslash is used as an escaping symbol in your input and the `-<letters>` part can be single or double, you may use

```
^-[A-Za-z]+(?:-[A-Za-z]+)?=[^\s\\]*(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6xYdC3/1)

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `-[A-Za-z]+` - a hyphen and then 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:-[A-Za-z]+)?` - an optional sequence of a hyphen and 1+ ASCII letters
- `=` - an equal sign
- `[^\s\\]*`  - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*`  - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\\.` - any escape sequence (if you use a DOTALL modifier, the `.` will also match  line break chars)
  - `[^\s\\]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `\`
- `$` - end of string.